# Accessing property from inside method using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm trying to access a `property` from inside an `object`. When I access the `property` by manually entering its *path*, I can retrieve it, but not when doing it *dynamically*.

What have I missed below?

```
var myApp = {
    cache : {},
    init: function() {
        myApp.cache.akey = 'A value'; // Set the cached value
        myApp.get('cache', 'akey'); 
    },
    get: function(from, key ) {
        console.log(myApp.from.key); // undefined
        console.log(myApp.cache.akey); // A value
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments 'from' and 'key' are not referenced in your example, instead the properties are literals.

Try

```
myApp[from][key]
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot access is literal, if you wanna access by string contained in a variable use subscript notation:

```
get: function(from, key ) {
    console.log(myApp[from][key]); // Assume from === "cache" and key === "akey", this accesses myApp.cache.akey

}
```